# How to Break For each in Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("registration").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable  FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
        for(DocumentSnapshot d:value){
       
            if(d.getId().equals(Name)){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User Name already exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
            else{
                is_userExists = false;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I want to break the foreach loop but the code isnt working properly

Comment: What does `d.getId().equals(Name)` retun?

Comment: Do you get this toast "User Name already exists" ? If not then there is not ID that matches with contents of name variable

Comment: `addSnapshotListener` doens't execute whenever you want … it executes to "synchronize" all your firebase data , and your phone so dont put your toast here … In the foreach just and ONLY copy all the `names` into a list (it has to be an attribute) . and whenever you want check duplication of Name read data from THAT list Not inside `addSnapshotListener`

Answer (score 1):

Use return keyword instead of break;

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("registration").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable  FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                            for(DocumentSnapshot d:value){
                           
                                if(d.getId().equals(Name)){
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User Name already exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    return;
                                }
                                else{
                                    is_userExists = false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be more logical to do this operation with a void method and return instead of break.

Answer (score 0):

Your Break should work as you want, nothing wrong with it.

What could be happening here is one of the following:

1. d.getId().equals(Name) results in false because they are not equal
2. d.getId() results in NullPointerException because d was not constructed earlier
3. onEvent is not even called...

In this answer I assume your code compiles.